# GoogleMaps Marker setVisible is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I cannot set a marker in a marker cluster invisible by looping my array of markers. I always get the message `Uncaught TypeError: Property 't' of object [object Object] is not a function` Which translates to setVisible is not a function in my case. (Found out after debugging in chrom)

The following code is used (simplified):

```
var markers = [];
function placeMarker() {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: pinImage,
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}

function deleteMarkers() {
    if (markers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
        }
        markers = [];
    }
}
```

The error is thrown in `deleteMarkers` on the line with `markers[i].setVisible(false);` What causes this error to be thrown? It seems like the marker is placed inside the array as `Object` instead of `google.maps.Marker`

Comment: This is by certainty not the code causing the error. BTW, where do you get `position` and `map` from? Here is a working demo using your code -> http://jsfiddle.net/VpK29/

Comment: If i debug my script in chrome or in firefox of my colleague it crashes on that exact row mentioned in my post. As the site using this js is not published, I may not show you my whole code. I try to make a fiddle with more code ;-)
Position is a `new LatLng()` created by values from a json result of our own webservice. `map` is initialized in an initialize method called by `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem myself in a way that works, but which is not the best way imho.
I had this script embedded in my source

```
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The error wasnt thrown by google maps but instead by the call to `removeMarker` on the clusterer:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'visible_changed', function () {
    if (marker.getVisible()) {
        markerCluster.addMarker(marker, true);
    } else {
        markerCluster.removeMarker(marker, true);
    }
});
```

All I did was removing `_compiled` from the script (As I wanted to know what goes wrong in this code). But instead of finding the source of this error, the code began to work.
I think there's something interfering with our scripts in the compiled version, as we have many js scripts on our site.

So the problem is fixed for me, as we embed the script as uncompiled version.